Python MySQL: DatabaseError: 1364 (HY000): Field 'emp_no' doesn't have a default value
I've installed MySQL on my Windows desktop.  The installation was successful.   I downloaded the employees data from github and added it to my MySql server.  I confirmed that through the MySQL 8.4 Command Line Client
I'm working through the Documentation for the MySQL Connector/Python Developer Guide.  I got to inserting data into the employee database.  I get this error: DatabaseError: 1364 (HY000): Field 'emp_no' doesn't have a default value
The answers to this question are about PHP, not python: mysql error 1364 Field doesn't have a default values
This question is about default values for Datetime: How do you set a default value for a MySQL Datetime column?
Except for the **config, this code is a cut-n-paste from the dev.mysql.com hyperlink.  And except for the 'password': '****', here's the code that I used:
from __future__ import print_function
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
import mysql.connector

config = {
    'user': 'root',
    'password': '****',
    'host': '127.0.0.1',
    'database': 'employees'
}

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
cursor = cnx.cursor()

tomorrow = datetime.now().date() + timedelta(days=1)

add_employee = ("INSERT INTO employees "
               "(first_name, last_name, hire_date, gender, birth_date) "
               "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")
add_salary = ("INSERT INTO salaries "
              "(emp_no, salary, from_date, to_date) "
              "VALUES (%(emp_no)s, %(salary)s, %(from_date)s, %(to_date)s)")

data_employee = ('Geert', 'Vanderkelen', tomorrow, 'M', date(1977, 6, 14))

# # Insert new employee
# cursor.execute(add_employee, data_employee)
# emp_no = cursor.lastrowid

# # Insert salary information
# data_salary = {
#   'emp_no': emp_no,
#   'salary': 50000,
#   'from_date': tomorrow,
#   'to_date': date(9999, 1, 1),
# }
# cursor.execute(add_salary, data_salary)

# # Make sure data is committed to the database
# cnx.commit()

cursor.close()
cnx.close()

Now, I know it connects because if I comment out the two Insert blocks, it runs fine.  But here is the error message when it runs as posted in this question.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Python\Tutorials\.venv\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 697, in cmd_query
    self._cmysql.query(
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Field 'emp_no' doesn't have a default value

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Documents\Python\Tutorials\Add_to_Employees.py", line 27, in <module>
    cursor.execute(add_employee, data_employee)
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Python\Tutorials\.venv\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 372, in execute
    result = self._cnx.cmd_query(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Python\Tutorials\.venv\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\opentelemetry\context_propagation.py", line 102, in wrapper
    return method(cnx, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Python\Tutorials\.venv\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 705, in cmd_query
    raise get_mysql_exception(
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1364 (HY000): Field 'emp_no' doesn't have a default value

DISCLAIMER:  I know not to put my password in the file.  I trying to solve one problem at a time.
EDIT:
When I ALTER TABLE employees MODIFY emp_no INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT; in MySQL 8.4 Command Line Client,I get this error:
ERROR 1833 (HY000): Cannot change column 'emp_no': used in a foreign key constraint 'dept_manager_ibfk_1' of table 'employees.dept_manager'

Here's the TABLE DEFINITON



You haven't posted a schema, so you may need to apply some interpretation to this. Your add_employee query is providing name, here date, birthdate etc, but not emp_no. MySQL is assuming that a default value is set in the schema that it can use, but you haven't defined one. Most likely you need to set emp_no to AUTO_INCREMENT so that unique employee numbers are assigned.

Show us the table definition for employees.  I'm betting it has an emp_no column that is required, but your insert statement did not provide a value for it.

Thank you both.  That gives me a direction to follow up on.

ERROR 1833 (HY000): Cannot change column 'emp_no': used in a foreign key constraint 'dept_manager_ibfk_1' of table 'employees.dept_manager'

You are getting this error because emp_no is already a foreign key in the following tables:

dept_emp
salaries
dept_manager
titles

You need to temporarily drop these foreign key constraints, modify the column, and then re-add the constraints.

Drop foreignt key constraints.
 ALTER TABLE dept_emp DROP FOREIGN KEY dept_emp;
 ALTER TABLE dept_manager DROP FOREIGN KEY dept_manager;
 ALTER TABLE salaries DROP FOREIGN KEY salaries;
 ALTER TABLE titles DROP FOREIGN KEY titles;


Modify the emp_no column.
 ALTER TABLE employees MODIFY emp_no INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;


Re-add the dropped foreign keys to tables.
 ALTER TABLE dept_emp ADD CONSTRAINT dept_emp FOREIGN KEY (emp_no) REFERENCES employees(emp_no);
 ALTER TABLE dept_manager ADD CONSTRAINT dept_manager FOREIGN KEY (emp_no) REFERENCES employees(emp_no);
 ALTER TABLE salaries ADD CONSTRAINT salaries FOREIGN KEY (emp_no) REFERENCES employees(emp_no);
 ALTER TABLE titles ADD CONSTRAINT titles FOREIGN KEY (emp_no) REFERENCES employees(emp_no);



Maybe this will help https://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/mysql-change-datatype-column-foreign-key-constraint

Once I add the FOREIGN KEY after dropping the FOREIGN KEY, do the restored tables contain all of the same information that they held originally?

Yeah, there is no effect on any rows of data.

I think the problem starts with the MySQL database employees table. This table doesn't have a default value or auto-increment for emp_no. Therefore, you have to add emp_no manually while inserting data, like below:
add_employee = ("INSERT INTO employees "
               "(emp_no, first_name, last_name, hire_date, gender, birth_date) "
               "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")

Alternatively, you can change your table to have emp_no as an auto-increment field:
ALTER TABLE employees MODIFY emp_no INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

Or, drop the table and recreate it with emp_no set to auto-increment:
DROP TABLE employees;

CREATE TABLE employees (
    emp_no INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name VARCHAR(50),
    last_name VARCHAR(50),
    hire_date DATE,
    gender ENUM('M', 'F'),
    birth_date DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_no)
);


Do I ALTER TABLE from the MySQL 8.4 Command Line Client or from the python script? Is the change permanent or does it only last as long as that current connection is on.

Do it using MySQL 8.4 Command Line, because there is no point in doing this using a Python script. Once it is done, it does not need to be done again. It permanently changes the table.

I modified the question with the error when I ALTER TABLE in MySQL 8.4 Command Line Client, and posted the Table Definition.

wrote another answer because it was too long for a comment.
